# Changing WampServer PHP Web version

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I installed WampServer 3.1.3 and I can't find an option to switch to a different PHP version for Web. All the tutorials and questions on StackOverflow have very different system tray context menu and none of them helped me solving my issue. I can only change the CLI PHP version, while the version I see with phpversion() in browser still shows PHP 5.6.35.

For example this question's only answer has quite different menu. It is the same that is seen in other tutorials or SO questions: [Using PHP 7 with WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153047/using-php-7-with-wamp)

[Context menu that I see looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmI9D.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Left Click on the icon or simply click on the icon it will open a menu like shown in the picture.
[how to change the php version in wampserver 3.1.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fwfq.png)
You are right clicking on that icon that's why this happens.